# How to multiply all numerical columns of a dataframe by a one-dimensional array?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe `df` of shape r x c, with 1 text column (with non-unique values) and the other columns all floats.
I then have an array `mult` of size r.
I would like each numerical column of the dataframe to be multiplied by the corresponding item of the array.

Ie the desired output is that value_1[0] should become value_1[0] * mult[0], value_2[0] should become value_2[0] * mult[0], etc.

What is an easy way to do it?

I have tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['txt']=['a','b','c','a','d']
df['value_1'] = np.arange(0,5)
df['value_2'] = np.arange(10,15)

mult = np.array([1,1,0,0,1])

newdf = df * mult

newdf2 = df.set_index('txt') * np.array
```

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input.

Comment: do you mean you need `newdf = df * mult[:,None]`?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  We like to see details - wrong results, errors, etc.  If you take the error messages seriously you might even find your own solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1689]: x = df.select_dtypes(int).columns

In [1690]: df[x] = df.select_dtypes('int').mul(mult, axis=0)

In [1691]: df
Out[1691]: 
  txt  value_1  value_2
0   a        0       10
1   b        1       11
2   c        0        0
3   a        0        0
4   d        4       14
```

Comment: Do we really need `pd.Series(mult)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Oh yes, its not needed. I've updated my answer. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to represent `mult` as a column vector before doing the multiplication. So the following should work:

```
df * mult[:,None]
```

Study `mult.shape` and `mult[:,None].shape` to see the differences.